# Django method exists() not working, error "referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, django, django-views

after long time passed at searched a solution, i not advanced for a reason.

I try of make operate the functionality "if exists():" for "User.username" of the user, and so avoid the duplicate username in my  webSite,but this is not work.

this is my code in views.py :

```
def edit_profil(request, pk=id):
    error_name = reverse_lazy('profil_edit')
    template_name="blog/edit_profil.html"
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditProfilForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            usernameDatas = form.cleaned_data['username']
        if User.objects.filter(username=usernameDatas).exists():
            messages.error(request, 'This is Username already exists !')
            return redirect(error_name)
        else:
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            user.username=usernameDatas
            user.save()
        return redirect('/blog/profil')
    else:
        form = EditProfilForm(instance=request.user)
        return render(request, template_name, locals())
```

The error received is: 
    "local variable 'usernameDatas' referenced before assignment"

Where is my error ? thanks all.

Comment: Well the error is not related to `.exists()` itself. The `form` is simply invalid, and thus `usernameDatas` is then *not* assigned. You probably want to *inline* the code into the `if` body.

Comment: Your `form` is ***not valid***, hence python won't go inside the **`if`** clause...

Answer (score 1):

`.exists()` is *not* the origin of the problem. This is a rather *generic* error in Python. It means that you *use* a variable *before* you assigned a value to it. Now in the `.exists()` line, only one local variable is used: `usernameDatas`. So it is likely that this variable is not assigned.

If we now look at possible scenario's where it is not valid, we see that this can happen if the `form.is_valid()` fails (returns `False`). The most straightforward way to handle this is by inlining the part:

```
def edit_profil(request, pk=id):
    error_name = reverse_lazy('profil_edit')
    template_name="blog/edit_profil.html"
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditProfilForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            usernameDatas = form.cleaned_data['username']
            # inline relevant parts
            if User.objects.filter(username=usernameDatas).exists():
                messages.error(request, 'This is Username already exists !')
                return redirect(error_name)
            else:
                user = form.save(commit=False)
                user.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                user.username=usernameDatas
                user.save()
                return redirect('/blog/profil')
    else:
        form = EditProfilForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, template_name, locals())
```

Note however that the above is an elegant way to tackle the problem. If you specify `unique=True` for the `username` field of the related Django model, then the form will *automatically validate this*. Furthermore you specify paths in the `redirct(..)` instead of the name of a view, which makes it senstive to URL changes. Finally using `locals()` is a severe anti-pattern: it is better to pass a dictionary with the variables you use.

Comment: Big Thanks all, i delete function locals(), thanks. I specify the paths in the redirect(..) as in the docs dango (http/shortcuts/#redirect), i have understood my error, but your code does not work : for example when I change my name with an existing user, the name that is a lining appears as if it is saved without being saved, very weird '-'. And my "messages.error" not work, but it's not important for the moment.
For use "unique=True", I use the User Model of django, it's functional because it's not saved the double username, but not return of message error for inform the user

Comment: But if the `User` exists with this name, then - given I understand your message correctly - it should *not* be saved, since then you create a new user with the same username. So the useername should be new (unique).

Comment: Yes, the user must be "unique", the feature works by default because I'm using the "User model" => "django.contrib.auth.models", 
I am trying to configure the code with "if exist ():" to possibly return an "error message" to the user when he enters an already existing "username" I do not have one and that is ugly. And your code avoids my error from my first subject message, but as I said above, your code has a very strange operation, it does not return my "message.error" and "duplicate" the username already existing whitout save.

Comment: @Ninja0x: it does, but since you redirect, you "refresh" the page. If you specify that the field is unique in the model, the form itself will error. I would *remove* the `redirect(..)`, and thus return the rendered page with the form. Django will then render the form with the error.

Comment: I'm really sorry to bother you so much, removing redirect does not really solve the problem, I better explain here https://paste.ee/p/ZQ07C

Comment: @Ninja0x: you should not put anything at that place. Simply let the control flow pass to `render(..)` this will render the *form* into the HTML page.

Comment: Ok it's good, I added "{% if form.errors%}" in my "html" page, it's a beginner's forgetfulness >.<  . very thanks !! I last little problem, why when I enter an already existing user, in my nav bar the already existing user name is displayed?

Comment: @Ninja0x: in case of errors, the form (with the values) is returned, so that a user can *correct* the form. For example if `foo@bar` is rejected (the error can for example say "not a valid email address"), the user has only to add `.com` to it. The fact that here it is because the uniqness constraint is violated is irrelevant: it will always render the form with the old data such that a user can conveniently modify it, and retry submitting it.